# Find <a> Element href #value in JavaScript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my link

```
<a href="#report" id="myreport">Generate Report</a>
```

It can be executed as

```
$('a#myreport').click(function () {/* codes */});
```

or

```
document.getElementById("myreport")
```

But how can I execute this from 'href' (element as 'report') instead of ID?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy:

```
$('a[href=#report]').click(function() { 
    /* your code */ 
});
```

You can access attributes with `[attrname=attrvalue]`. Of course, you can omit the attribute-value and just select elements with any attribute set.

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery, you can use the [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) to achieve it easily, look:

```
$("a[href*='report']").click(function () {
     /* codes */
 });
```

Look at my jsFiddle live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ynevet/K4zZH/

From jQuery docs:

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value
>   containing the a given substring.

Comment: Your answer is not 100% exact. The `*`-prefix in front of the `=` means only contains. But he/you should omit the `*` and prefix the attribute-value with `#` to fetch only this one link and not any other link where a target contains something with `report` like an external link to a reporting website or idontknow.

Comment: @omeinusch _to fetch only this one link and not any other link_ statement, theoretically, is also impossible with your solution, there could be multiple links with a `#report` value in their `href` attribute. without ID, you can't ensure uniqueness in this case.